# select max(primary_key) bad performance in clickhouse with partition by toYearWeek

Tags: query-optimization, partitioning, clickhouse

The following clickhouse table is partitioned by week of the year `PARTITION BY toYearWeek(receive_time_utc)` and ordered by primary key where time is first element of the primary key tuple: `ORDER BY (receive_time_utc, seqno, rowno)`

However, `SELECT max(receive_time_utc) FROM roq_bbo_okx` seems to do full scan of the table, instead of last partition only.

Could it be due to optimizer does not understand toYearWeek function? I also so people using toYYYYMM function and intDivs

```
CREATE TABLE default.roq_bbo_okx
(
    `gateway` LowCardinality(String),
    `session_id` UUID CODEC(LZ4),
    `seqno` UInt64 CODEC(DoubleDelta, LZ4),
    `rowno` UInt32 DEFAULT 0 CODEC(DoubleDelta, LZ4),
    `receive_time_utc` DateTime64(9, 'UTC') CODEC(DoubleDelta, LZ4),
    `exchange_time_utc` DateTime64(9, 'UTC') CODEC(DoubleDelta, LZ4),
    `origin_create_time_utc` DateTime64(9, 'UTC') DEFAULT receive_time_utc CODEC(DoubleDelta, LZ4),
    `snapshot` Int8 CODEC(LZ4),
    `exchange` LowCardinality(String) CODEC(LZ4),
    `symbol` LowCardinality(String) CODEC(LZ4),
    `type` Enum8('UNDEFINED' = 0, 'BID' = 48, 'ASK' = 49, 'TRADE' = 50, 'IMPLIED_BID' = 69, 'IMPLIED_ASK' = 70, 'BOOK_RESET' = 74) DEFAULT 'UNDEFINED' CODEC(LZ4),
    `action` Enum8('UNDEFINED' = 0, 'NEW' = 48, 'CHANGE' = 49, 'DELETE' = 50) DEFAULT 'UNDEFINED' CODEC(LZ4),
    `side` Enum8('UNDEFINED' = 0, 'BUY' = 48, 'SELL' = 49) DEFAULT 'UNDEFINED' CODEC(LZ4),
    `price_tick` Float64 DEFAULT toFloat64(nan) CODEC(Gorilla, LZ4),
    `price_i` Int64 DEFAULT -9223372036854775808 CODEC(DoubleDelta, LZ4),
    `qty_tick` Float64 DEFAULT toFloat64(nan) CODEC(Gorilla, LZ4),
    `qty_i` Int64 DEFAULT -9223372036854775808 CODEC(DoubleDelta, LZ4),
    `posno` UInt32 DEFAULT 0 CODEC(DoubleDelta, LZ4),
    `num_orders` UInt16 CODEC(Gorilla, LZ4),
    `trade_id` String CODEC(LZ4)
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PARTITION BY toYearWeek(receive_time_utc)
PRIMARY KEY (receive_time_utc, seqno, rowno)
ORDER BY (receive_time_utc, seqno, rowno)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
```

Comment: it looks like situation is better with 22.5.1 version of clickhouse. Slowness was observed with 21.4.6

Answer (score 0):

There is no such optimization yet. CH is unable to use primary index for `max()`. In some simple cases CH is able to use a virtual projection based on partition.idx (partition columns).

You can do manual optimization `order by ...desc limit 1`

```sql
SELECT max(receive_time_utc) 
FROM roq_bbo_okx 
order by receive_time_utc desc limit 1
```